# MySQL "bad handshake" after entering password

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I'm having problem to connect to the remote DB from the terminal as follow

```
mysql -u db_user -p -h 10.100.1.100
Enter password:
```

afer entering password I'm getting that error:

```
ERROR 1043 (08S01): Bad handshake
```

and I can connect to the DB from a PC using MySQL Workbench.

Running MySQL  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73 for CentOS6

Comment: This belongs in dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: What version of the MySQL client did you use?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ver 8.0.16

Comment: And what version of MySQL Workbench did you try, that worked properly?

Comment: 5.1 and 8.0 are 4 _major_ versions apart.  Although MySQL generally maintains compatibility, this is pushing your luck.

Comment: v5.1.73 is not compatible with v8.x of the workbench.  You need to go back to v6.3 if you need a confirmed working version for right now.

Answer (score 1):

Is connector are compatible with your version? (if you upgraded db recently this may be case) Or Possibly bug try with upgraded version on both db and connector. I can see some similar bugs on mysql portals. Bad handshake most of the time mean both master and clients are not compatible.